# List of Root Hints Empty Windows Server 2008 DNS

Tags: windows-server-2008, domain-name-system

I did a fresh install of the DNS server package on Windows Server 2008 and had problems accessing any *.com site (google.com, cbs.com....).  It wasn't until I dug into it that I saw that my Root Hints list was empty.

I thought the default behavior was to have the Root Hints set up and configured?

Did I misunderstand that?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A default installation of the DNS server role should have root hints unless the server has a root zone - .(root). If the server has a root zone then delete it. If the server doesn't have a root zone and there are no root servers listed on the Root Hints tab of the DNS server properties then the server may be missing the cache.dns file in the %systemroot%\system32\dns directory, which is where the list of root servers is loaded from. In the case of the root server list being empty you can:

1. Add the root servers manually
2. Copy the list of root servers from another DNS server
3. Copy the cache.dns file from another server to this server

Comment: I've added the list of root servers from `a.root-servers.net.` I don't have another DNS server to copy the cache.dns file from. Is there any danger to not having the cache.dns file? Thanks

Comment: I'm not sure, but this article seems to describe your situation. See if it's relevant and if so, follow it's instructions. Also, unbeknownst to me, a copy of the cache.dns file is located at %systemroot%\system32\dns\samples.

Comment: Awesome, thanks! Looks like your link got hosed, could you re input it?